# Making an extension for multiple versions of Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, sdk

I have a feeling that the Visual Studio SDK is targeted heavily towards the version of Visual Studio it is created for, so I'm wondering how to do this in the best way possible. I currently only have Visual Studio 2008, but people using Visual Studio 2010 have begun wanting to use my tool as well, and I want to help them out. There were some using Visual Studio 2005 as well. Is there any way to do this without maintaining two (or three) different versions of the tool in different versions of Visual Studio?

Comment: Any progress on this?  I'm having trouble with the WiX and the regpkg file's [$componentpath] ... and probably other topics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is related, maybe it helps: [Does Visual Studio 2010 have backward compatibility with visual studio 2008's addins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/789505/does-visual-studio-2010-have-backward-compatibility-with-visual-studio-2008s-add)

Comment: Thanks for your input. The question you linked to seems more speculative than definitive, and it doesn't really answer my question, but again, your input was much appreciated.