# How can I prepare a Visual Studio add-in for multiple Visual Studio versions?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-addins

I have Visual Studio 2012 installed, and I want to create a new Visual Studio add-in. In the creation wizard I get this window:

[image: application host]

I would have liked to create an add-in for other (previous) versions as well. Is it possible, and if so, how do I do that? I understand VS 2008 uses a different addin mechanism, but is there a way to at least add VS 2010 to that list?

I've read [Developing Visual Studio addins for multiple versions of Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13495654/developing-visual-studio-addins-for-multiple-versions-of-visual-studio), but couldn't really understand from it *how* to add VS 2010.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way would be to create addin project in VS2010 and then import it to VS2012 if you want to develop in 2012.

Otherwise you would need to create addin as for VS2012 and then perform several steps:

- change project framework to 4.0
- edit .AddIn file to set HostApplication Version to 10.0
- update all references to use VS2010 SDK
- set Debug external program and working directory to VS2010
- possibly few other steps